# How to achieve GLSL vec* constructing syntax without compiler being smart in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, syntax-error, glsl

In **GLSL**, we can do that

```
vec4 v = vec4(vec3(10.f, 20.f, 30.f), 1.f);
```

So I tried to do it in C++

```
struct vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
    vec3(){}
    vec3(float all) : x(all), y(all), z(all) {}
    vec3(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c){}
};

struct vec4
{
    float x, y, z, w;
    vec4() {}
    vec4(float all) : x(all), y(all), z(all), w(all) {}
    vec4(float a, float b, float c, float d) : x(a), y(b), z(c), w(d) {}
    // Here is the trick
    vec4(vec3 v3, float d) : x(v3.x), y(v3.y), z(v3.z), w(d) {}
};
```

It works but the problem is that I can initialize **vec4** with only **two** floats... seems like the compiler replaces `vec4(a, b);` with `vec4(vec3(a), b);` at compile-time which is what I *don't* want because it's confusing and unwanted, I'd be more likely to throw an error but how?

```
int main()
{
    vec3 V3 = vec3(10.f, 20.f, 30.f);
    vec4 V4;
    // Works
    V4 = vec4(V3, 1.f);
    // This also works which is a problem.
    V4 = vec4(10.f, 1.f); // == vec4(vec3(10.f), 1.f);
}
```

Comment: You would need to add those behaviors by creating constructors that take those types.

Comment: I don't get you... What's wrong with these constructors..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is to specify the method [`deleted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) in the `vec4` class:

```
vec4(float a, float b) = delete;
```

Then if you try to create a `vec4` with two numbers it will just complain at an attempt to use a deleted method.

> a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   a.cpp:27:24: error: use of deleted function ‘vec4::vec4(float, float)’
>        V4 = vec4(10.f, 1.f); // == vec4(vec3(10.f), 1.f);

Of course the error message isn't the best, but at least there will be an error and no implicit conversions.

---

Another way that gives a better error message, but might change functionality elsewhere, is to specify the constructor of `vec3` as [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). This means the compiler is not allowed to convert a `float` into a `vec3` implicitly:

```
explicit vec3(float all) : x(all), y(all), z(all) {}
```

This causes the following error:

> a.cpp:26:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘vec4::vec4(float, float)’
>        V4 = vec4(10.f, 1.f); // == vec4(vec3(10.f), 1.f);
>
> a.cpp:16:5: note: candidate: vec4::vec4(vec3, float)
>        vec4(vec3 v3, float d) : x(v3.x), y(v3.y), z(v3.z), w(d) {}
>
> a.cpp:16:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘float’ to ‘vec3’

So it's clear why this error happens, but if at some point you would like to have implicit conversions this of course disallows that.

Comment: The second method is what I was looking for... thank you :)